# extending core controller on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have placed this controller on application/core, called MY_base.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Base_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
}

function set_spaces($post_array, $primary_key){
      $post_array['nombre']=str_replace(" ", "_", $post_array['nombre']);
      return $post_array;
}

}
?>
```

and this controller on the controllers folder

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clase extends Base_Controller {

 function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
 }

 function index(){
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

   $this->grocery_crud->set_table('clase');
   $this->grocery_crud->set_subject('Clase');
   $this->grocery_crud->required_fields('nombre');
   $this->grocery_crud->unset_columns('id');
   $this->grocery_crud->unset_print();
   $this->grocery_crud->unset_export();
   $this->grocery_crud->unset_add();
   $this->grocery_crud->callback_before_update(array($this,'set_spaces'));
  //$this->grocery_crud->set_theme('datatables');
   $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();
  //$this->load->view('header', $data);
   $this->load->view('header2.php',$output);
   $this->load->view('clase_view', $output);

 }
 else{

  redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
}
}
?>
```

I think I've followed documentation's instructions correctly but I get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Base_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\esi3d\application\controllers\clase.php on line 3
```

It looks like is looking for base_controler on controllers folder not in core folder.

Comment: Try rename your file from `MY_base.php` to `Base_Controller.php`.

Comment: I already solved this problem ,thank you

Comment: @AFS what changes you have done to solve your problem??

Comment: I renamed the file and the class to MY_Controller

Answer (score 0):

Place your MY_base.php also in controllers folder